# How to detect a click on any window's title bar?

Tags: macos, event-handling, nswindow, osx-lion

I would like to detect a mouse down-up on an NSWindow. In fact, I'm looking to add functionality to the system as a whole by detecting a click on any NSWindow's title bar. However, I do not see access to anything like the title bar or chrome in an NSWindow. I suppose I could listen for any click and do the math to detect if the click was within the title bar based on the size and location of the window, but I wanted to know if there was a better way. Thanks!

Comment: Did you get any luck in finding the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to listen to mouseDown events on window's frame. Window's frame is hidden under [[window contentView] superview]. You could either subclass NSWindow and create your own implementation of frame's NSView (I think it' a bit of work) or try to replace just the mouseDown method with your own. In here http://parmanoir.com/Custom_NSThemeFrame it is shown how you can do something like this for drawRect method. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. That's a good point that I'll test out. I was mostly interested in a system plugin, to detect this on ANY window, though.

Comment: Excellent suggestion, adding the trackingArea to NSWindow's `self.contentView?.superview` allows to detect mouse events on the titleBar as well...